# React Native: When/how to start network requests?

Tags: javascript, react-native

While playing around with React Native, I stumbled upon an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. I have a main `NavigatorIOS` view where the contents `push` and `pop` around the various views. I had initially set it up in such a way that a network request would be started in `componentDidMount`. However, what started to happen is that the "pushing" of the navigation (the animation of moving to the next screen) would be delayed until the actual request had been completed (even though the loading makes use of `fetch`, promises and `async/await` functions). I managed to offset most of these issues by wrapping the network request code in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` call, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to handle this. Both `requestAnimationFrame` and `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` didn't work, and even the `setTimeout` is finicky. Are there any better ways to do this?

Just for illustration, this is approximately how my code works (pseudo-code):

**Screen 1**:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.navigator.push({ data })} />
```

**Screen 2**:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.startLoading();
}

startLoading() {
  this.setState({ items: [], loading: true });
  this.load().then(items => this.setState({ items, loading: false }));
}

async load() {
  const contents = await fetch(this.props.url);
  // Process contents.
  return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting default data in getInitialState?

```
var TouchableHighlight = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      items: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` function doesn't immediately trigger a rendering event, so `startLoading` doesn't need the first line. Setting a initial state, like Vinnie's answer, is a better solution to that.

I see you're using es7, but could you try this instead?

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url)
        .then(result => this.setState({items: processContents(result), loading: false}))
        .catch(e => console.log("error", e))
}

processContents(fetchResult) {
    // do whatever
    return {};
}
```